Mongo query to ignore non English characters
I have a mongo collection that stores city/country data in multiple languages. For example, the following query:
db.cities_database.find({ "name.pl.country": "Węgry" }).pretty().limit(10);
Returns data in the following format:
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId('67331d2a9566994a18c505aa'),
    geoname_id_city: 714073,
    latitude: 46.91667,
    longitude: 21.26667,
    geohash: 'u2r4guvvmm4m',
    country_code: 'HU',
    population: 7494,
    estimated_radius: 400,
    feature_code: 'PPL',
    name: {
      pl: { city: 'Veszto', admin1: null, country: 'Węgry' },
      ascii: { city: 'veszto', admin1: null, country: null },
      lt: { city: 'Veszto', admin1: null, country: 'Vengrija' },
      ru: { city: 'Veszto', admin1: null, country: 'Венгрия' },
      hu: { city: 'Veszto', admin1: null, country: 'Magyarország' },
      en: { city: 'Veszto', admin1: null, country: 'Hungary' },
      fr: { city: 'Veszto', admin1: null, country: 'Hongrie' }
    }
  }
...
]

I want to be able to use the same query while using English only characters, so for this example I'd like to query by "name.pl.country": "Wegry" (Instead character ę I'd like Mongo to treat it as e while performing this query).
Is it possible to achieve this?
So far I tried using collation like this:
db.cities_database.find({ "name.pl.country": "Wegry" }).collation({ locale: "pl", strength: 1 }).pretty().limit(10);
but this query doesn't return anything.

I wonder if it's a bug in the Polish locale in MongoDB. Because it works with French locale: db.cities_database.find({ "name.pl.country": "Wegry" }).collation({ locale: "fr", strength: 1 }).

Umm the issue might be that my understanding about that was wrong. Maybe setting locale to "fr" means that it will use French language rules when querying, sorting etc... Because ę  doesn't exist in French it treats it as e and that why it works. It does exist in Polish so it treats e and ę as different characters therefore nothing is returned in the query.

"Because ę doesn't exist in French it treats it as e and that why it works" - No, I don't think so. For example, that extra thing on the letter ę is an Ogonek and exists in Lithuanian as well. So it tried the query above with locale: "lt" and it worked. If it the rule was "will not convert if the letter exists" then it should not work for Lithuanian either.

Apart from why it's not working with locale: "pl", a workaround to have a general query for all languages would be with English: collation({ locale: "en", strength: 1 })

yeah I think this works but I think it causes another issue - can't use regex with collation. Apparently The $regex implementation is not collation-aware

I have no knowledge in Polish and I don't know the difference between e and ę. But if you use MongoDB Altas, you can set up a customAnalyzer with icuFolding to perform diacritics-insensitive search.
The index:
{
  "analyzer": "diacriticFolder",
  "mappings": {
    "fields": {
      "name": {
        "type": "document",
        "fields": {
          "pl": {
            "type": "document",
            "fields": {
              "country": {
                "analyzer": "diacriticFolder",
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "analyzers": [
    {
      "name": "diacriticFolder",
      "charFilters": [],
      "tokenizer": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "tokenFilters": [
        {
          "type": "icuFolding"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

$search query:
[
  {
    $search: {
      "text": {
        "query": "Wegry",
        "path": "name.pl.country"
      }
    }
  }
]

MongoDB Atlas search playground

I think that's the way how the polish collation is defined, see Polish CLDR chart.
ę Ę are black, I guess that means "must match exactly".
Other characters (e.g. é É è È ê Ê ë Ë) are grey, for them it works:
db.collection.insertMany([
   { codepoint: 'U+00EBU', name: 'Latin Small Letter E with Diaeresis', char: 'ë' },
   { codepoint: 'U+0119', name: 'Latin Small Letter E with Ogonek', char: 'ę' },
   { codepoint: 'U+0065', name: 'Latin Small Letter E', char: 'e' }
])

When you query them it gives
db.collection.find({ char: "ë" }).collation({ locale: "pl", strength: 1 })
[
  { name: 'Latin Small Letter E with Diaeresis', char: 'ë' },
  { name: 'Latin Small Letter E', char: 'e' }
]

db.collection.find({ char: "ę" }).collation({ locale: "pl", strength: 1 })
[
  { name: 'Latin Small Letter E with Ogonek', char: 'ę' }
]

db.collection.find({ char: "e" }).collation({ locale: "pl", strength: 1 })
[
  { name: 'Latin Small Letter E with Diaeresis', char: 'ë' },
  { name: 'Latin Small Letter E', char: 'e' }
]

Maybe you are looking for
db.cities_database.find({ "name.pl.country": "Wegry" }).collation({ locale: "en_US_POSIX", strength: 1 })

